# USF4 - Menus are just black screen

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv

I am trying to play USF4 in Winodws 10 using a RX570 and an I3 9100F INTEL CPU.

The problem I am having is that I can see the Capcom logo, the Nvidia Logo and even the intro video. But as soon as I reach the main Menu I can hear the announcer scream the game's title but the screen is pitch black. If I do not touch anything then the demo of two random fighters is played and I can see everything. The game runs perfectly fine. But if i press start to acces the main menu again then everything goes back to black. I can press up and down and select stuff blindly but i cant see anything.

One other thing to notice is that the menues besides being pitch black have no BGM. I remember for sure there is music in the main menu and in the character selection screen.

Is someone aware of a solution to this problem?

The exact same issue is discussed here : https://steamcommunity.com/app/45760/discussions/0/34094415754258740/

Answer (score 1):

This happened because I had corrupted/missing DirectX dlls.

The solution for this is to download DirectX 9,10,11 and 12 installers and just run them.

Once all the files are present the game works perfectly fine.